# How to create simple read/write login to specific folder on Linux server? (ftp/ssh/other..)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ftp, vsftpd

I've got a simple Ubuntu (14.04) server. I now want to give ftp or ssh access to a specific folder to a friend of mine. Either ftp or ssh would be fine, I'm just after a quick setup. The problem is now that finding a quick and dirty solution doesn't seem to be as easy as I hoped for.

I first checked out ssh for which I found [this blog](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/chroot-users-with-openssh-an-easier-way-to-confine-users-to-their-home-directories/), which seems a bit too complicated for my basic linux knowledge. I can't find an easier/simpler solution for ssh though.

I then looked around for ftp solutions, for which vsftpd seems to be the way to go. Looking through the [vsftpd config page](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html) I am totally lost though.

Does anybody have a quick and dirty way to give someone read and write access to a specific folder on a Linux server? No need for extremely tight security or best practices (many files are somewhat public anyway). Anything that works would be awesome!

Comment: Do you need authenticated access, or will anonymous access work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a normal Linux (especially Ubuntu) install, `ssh` is installed by default.

So, the quickest way to share a file/folder would be:

- Make a new user account for your friend
- Open root terminal
- `cd /home/{friends-account-name}`
- `ln -s {full-path-of-folder-you-want-to-share} {convenient-name-for-your-friend}`
- Make sure permissions of and in the folder (the original folder, not the link you just made with `ln`) you want to share allow your friend's account to access, i.e. the "world" or `chmod __X` part of the permissions.  Use `ls -al` to check permissions.

Your friend can now use `ssh` to login (or "Connect to Server" from Nautilus or similar) (or WinSCP from Windows) and will find a link to the folder you want to share when he logs in.

If you have anything in your home folder you need to have private, make sure the files/directories have `chmod __0` (e.g. chmod 770, etc.) permissions.

There are more advanced things you can do, such as `chroot` your friend to the home directory so he can't navigate out of it and such, but for quick and dirty use, the above will do.  Normal non-root user accounts can't do anything with system files so don't worry about that.

Comment: Thats awesome! I've setup new ssh users before but didn't think of the softlink trick. You've made my day ultrasawblade!